# Merge like array values to new grouped array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I need to combine like array values as follows:

**From:**

```
arr = ['abc', 'abc', 'eff', 'eff', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
```

**To:**

```
merged_like_arr = [ ['abc', 'abc'], ['eff', 'eff'], ['foo'], ['bar', 'bar', 'bar']]
```

Basically have an ActiveRecord object which returns a collection of records in order.

```
aff=Registration.order('affiliate DESC')
aff.map{|code| code. affiliate }
  # produces the following:
  # arr = ['abc', 'abc', 'eff', 'eff', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']
```

I need to be alter the data form `arr` to `merged_like_arr` (as shown above) so that I can do:

```
merged_like_arr.sort_by{|arr|-arr.size}.first(10)
 #=> [ ["bar", "bar", "bar"], ["eff", "eff"], ["abc", "abc"] ... ]
```

The purpose is to find the top 10 affiliates in the system by looking up how many times their affiliate id was used in the registration table.

Alternative implementations are also welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The purpose is to find the top 10 affiliates in the system by looking up how many times their affiliate id was used in the registration table.

You can use [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) with `group` for that kind of query:

> If `count` is used with `group`, it returns a Hash whose keys represent the aggregated column, and the values are the respective amounts:
>
> ```
> Person.group(:city).count
> # => { 'Rome' => 5, 'Paris' => 3 }
> ```

In your case:

```
Registration.group(:affiliate).count
#=> { 'abc' => 2, 'eff' => 2, 'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
arr = ['abc', 'abc', 'eff', 'eff', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']

arr = arr.group_by { |e| e }.values
# => [["abc", "abc"], ["eff", "eff"], ["foo"], ["bar", "bar", "bar"]]
```

Comment: I swear my brain farts are some of the stinkiest late at night. I could of sworn I tried that exact method 12 times before posting this question. Thanks pal! Final line of code: `affs.group_by { |e| e }.values.sort_by{|j|-j.size}.first(10)` Awesome... Temporarily leaving question open to see if "Alternative implementations" are offered. If not I will accept your answer...